# node: permission denied. How to fix?

Tags: node.js, permissions, debian

The permission for nodejs is showing blank. I am not sure how it got changed. I am not able to remove or start node. How to fix this?

```
/usr/bin# ls -la | grep node
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          45 Feb  1 14:40 corepack -> ../lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/corepack.js
----------  1 root root    75421096 Feb  1 08:05 node
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           4 Jun 26 00:44 nodejs -> node
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          38 Feb  1 14:40 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          38 Feb  1 14:40 npx -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
```

```
/usr/bin# node
-bash: /usr/bin/node: Permission denied
```

```
/usr/bin# chmod -v 777 node
chmod: changing permissions of 'node': Operation not permitted
failed to change mode of 'node' from 0000 (---------) to 0777 (rwxrwxrwx)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, re-installing node with NVM solved the issue:

Install nvm
nvm install 14
nvm use 14